# ng-model get undefined from route form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i working with route so i have a form in one route and i calling a post function with `ng-submit="addUser()` and i have a `ng-model` for all input values e.q `ng-model="fname"`, and i trying obtain the value from

```
$scope.addUser=function(){

            document.getElementById("message").textContent = "";
                                    alert( $scope.fname).....;
```

but alert get undefined
my route function:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
              function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider. when('/subpage/', {
                templateUrl: 'p0.html',
                controller: 'ItemsController'
                 }).when('/subpage2/:orderId', {
                    templateUrl: 'p1.html',
                    controller: 'ItemsController'
                 }) });
}]);
```

**Note: if the form is in main page(index.html), and no in subpage(route), i can obtain the "fname"**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, we need use a child property of an existing object 
example:

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.addUser=function(){

            document.getElementById("message").textContent = "";
                                    alert( $scope.form.fname).....;
```

and the ng-model :

```
<input ng-model="form.fname"/>
```

Hope this can help...